# Anyway to fix a leaky Water Heater Pressure Relief Valve?

Tags: water-heater, leaking

Leaky Water Heater Pressure Relief Valve (about a quart a month).
I have used it a few times to relieve the vacuum when draining the water heater to remove sediment, etc.
I am thinking maybe some debris got stuck in it.
So rather than buy one and install it next time i drain the tank I would rather be forced to buy one after failing to fix this one.
Anyone actually fix one?

Comment: If lucky flowing water though it might clean it out.  If it has been leaking a month or more, than the debris are probably embedded into the seal/seat.  They are probably not hard to take apart, but the problem is making sure they are adjusted right to open at the pressure needed to be safe when putting it back together.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1- open the valve while the HW tank is under pressure to try to flush the valve out.  NOTE, plenty of water will come out! be prepared to catch it in a bucket.   (This rarely works to cure the leaking valve, but you can take a shot)

2- buy an new valve and install it.  ( This has a very high success rate )

Comment: Remember that this valve is safety equipment. Attempting to repair the existing valve except by "flush it and hope" could actually be dangerous. Replacement is harder to get wrong.